# Best practice on including a rails partial that is shared among different resources?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Assuming a partial called `dope`, is the following the succinct way of including it from a view?

```
dealers.each do |dealer|
  = render partial: 'common/dope', locals: {dealer: dealer}
```

Answer (score 0):

IIRC you don't need the partial anymore so assuming you're doing this in haml, based on your syntax this would work

```
- dealers.each do |dealer|
  = render 'common/dope', locals: {dealer: dealer}
```

Comment: Thanks Dave. Removing the `partial` though doesn't look for a file called `_dope` instead it looks to find one called `dope`

Comment: weird cause that's counter to the expected behavior http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-partials so maybe is the context its being rendered in or your rails version. IIRC this changed in 3.1?